# Java Pass By Value Swap Method

Tags: java, swap

I'm trying to trace this pre-written code below.

I cannot understand how the following java swap method works for vector objects.  I'd expect the output of the following code to be (my Vector:)[6],[3],[1]  (your Vector:)[5],[1],[6].... but it's actually (myVector:) [5],[1],[6] (yourVector:) [6],[3],[1],[5],[1],[6]

Could anyone please explain this to me?  I'm trying to trace this code I guess I'm not understanding the "pass by value" part of java.

Thanks in advance.

```
public static void swapContents(Vector v1, Vector v2){
    Vector temp = v1;
    v1 = new Vector();
    for(int i = 0; i<v2.size(); i++)
        v1.add(v2.get(i));
    for(int j = 0; j< temp.size(); j++)
        v2.add(temp.get(j));
}


public static void main(String[] args){

   Vector myVector = new Vector();
   myVector.add(new Integer(5));
   myVector.add(new Integer(1));
   myVector.add(new Integer(6));

   Vector yourVector = new Vector();
   yourVector.add(new Integer(6));
   yourVector.add(new Integer(3));
   yourVector.add(new Integer(1));

   swapContents(myVector, yourVector);

   System.out.println(myVector);
   System.out.println(yourVector);
 }
```

Comment: Before adding values to `v2` in `swapContents()` method, You should remove previous values of `v2`.

Comment: @Varun i'm trying to trace this pre-written code.  I can't change it... so I'm trying to understand what it's doing

Comment: Your "pre-written code" is broken. See my answer below ...

Comment: @user3806226 It this code `swapContents()` method is copying all data of `yourVector` in `myVector` and adding all data of 'myVector` in `yourVector`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Java, you pass object references by value. This means that any changes you make to the objects will be reflected in the objects passed in, such as in this case:

```
myVector.add(v2.get(i))
```

This changes the object myVector which was passed in. However, any changes you make to the reference don't affect the calling objects. So something like this

```
myVector = new Vector();
```

Would not modify the original.

So what your code does is this

```
//Creates a new reference to the object passed in, v1
Vector temp = v1;
//Sets the reference v1 to point to a new object, which will not affect the originals
v1 = new Vector();
for(int i = 0; i<v2.size(); i++)
    //adds the contents of v2 into the new object
    //This has no impact on the original objects
    v1.add(v2.get(i));
for(int j = 0; j< temp.size(); j++)
    //adds the contents of what was passed in as v1 into v2
    v2.add(temp.get(j));
```

So in the end all this does is adds v1 onto the back of v2. v1 remains unchanged.
Here's [a link](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077424/learn-java/does-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value.html) with more information on Java's variable passing rules

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
public static void swapContents(Vector v1, Vector v2){
    Vector temp = v1;
    v1 = new Vector();
    for(int i = 0; i<v2.size(); i++)
        v1.add(v2.get(i));
    for(int j = 0; j< temp.size(); j++)
        v2.add(temp.get(j));
}
```

- First you save v1
- Then you make a new v1
- Then you add stuff to it from v2
- Then you add the v1 stuff to v2 (but v2 still has it's original contents...)

Comment: Worth noting that `myVector` remains unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

Moving the references around inside of the `swapContents` method isn't going to work.  Something like this would:

```
public static void swapContents(Vector v1, Vector v2){
    Vector tmp1 = new Vector(v1);
    Vector tmp2 = new Vector(v2);
    v1.clear();
    v2.clear();
    for(Object o : tmp1) {
      v2.add(o);
    }
    for(Object o : tmp2) {
      v1.add(o);
    }
}
```

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is making temp a reference to v1's values. Then you take v1, and assign it to a new empty vector (this is applied to the vector in your main method). Next you fill it with vector 2's values (6,3,1). v1 is now done.

Now v2 is left unchanged and still contains (6,3,1). You add in temp's values (which are still pointing at the old values of v1, (5,1,6) and put those on top of v2's current values.

Answer (score 0):

Objects are passed by reference in java.

```
Public static void swap(Vector v1,Vector v2) {
    Vector tmp = new Vector();
    for (object obj : v1) {
        tmp.add(obj);
    }
    v1.clear();
    for (object obj : v2) {
         v1.add(obj);
    }
    v2.clear();
    for (object obj : tmp) {
        v2.add(obj);
    }
}
```